# Playstore won't allow me to log into my google account

Tags: google-play-store

I have a Galaxy S5 and whenever I try to login to my google account to set up playstore I keep getting this same message. "Can't establish reliable connection to the server, this could be a temporary problem or your android device may not be provisioned for data services. If it continues, call customer care." I live in Mexico so we do not have data. I strictly go off of wifi and i currently have really good wifi here. Please let me know how to fix it. I have set the time and date. And still has not fixed my problem.

Answer (score 1):

If your galaxy s5 is rooted then you can fix this error by going into `/system/etc` and looking for a text file named `hosts`. Open it with any text editor and add this in front of `127.0.0.1`, `#`, e.g., `#127.0.0.1 localhost`. If it doesn't work, delete all text from the `hosts` file and paste this: `127.0.0.1 localhost` and save, then reboot. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this article](http://www.technipages.com/android-error-cant-establish-a-reliable-data-connection-to-the-server-when-adding-account) I would suggest trying the following:

1. Try resetting google apps as described on the (Instructions vary per device, but [this should work](http://www.itjungles.com/samsung-galaxy-s5-how-to-clear-app-cache-and-data.html) for your S5 -- You can also clear app data this way but try just the cache first.) You most likely need to clear the cache for the apps named "Play Store" and possibly "Google" or "Google App", and probably " Google Play Services"(**as a last resort**)
2. If you have physical access to the wifi router, try resetting it by power cycling it (unplugging it, waiting 30 seconds, and plugging it back in).
3. As a workaround, try logging in to the Youtube app and then sync it in the system account settings page.

Hope that helps.